# How am I supposed to find puzzle boxes?

Tags: streetpass-mii-plaza, streetpass-mansion-monster-manor

I've opened 550 chests in 43 floors and have only ever seen 2 puzzle boxes to even attempt. By extrapolating that, I won't be seeing all 50 puzzle boxes until floor 1075. That seems excessive, so clearly I'm missing something. Are puzzle box appearances not random?

Answer (score 3):

The puzzle box appearances are random. But, you may be missing some things:

> ### For a puzzle box to appear, a mii has to:
>
> - Own the game regardless of tags, or
> - Have two or more tags
>
> #### Note:
>
> - A Game owner mii gives you puzzle boxes its already completed.
> - A Non Game Owner 2+ tag mii guarantees you a new puzzle box.
>
> ### To receive a puzzle box from miis, you have to:
>
> - Already set the mii's piece, **and**
> - Make a 2x2 room or bigger in the same session

[Source](http://www.gamefaqs.com/3ds/625899-streetpass-mii-plaza/faqs/68659)

Comment: Downvoting for two reasons: 1. It's a link-only answer. 2. The text at that link says all I have to do is have a Mii with 2+ tags and make a room of 2x2 or bigger - yet I have Miis with 400+ tags and have made rooms of 2x2 several hundred times in the process of getting my aforementioned 550 chests. Needless to say this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Then there is something wrong with your 3ds, with all due respect.

Comment: I had actually considered that, but the other 3DS I tag with the game reports the same exasperation, so I kinda doubt it.